# Creating GlobalKTable using only subset of topic columns

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

We use kafka streams to process one input stream and one compacted topic with client data. In our stream processing we consume the first one and join it with the second one using a GlobalKTable, something like

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    
    GlobalKTable<String, Client> clients
        = builder.globalTable(CLIENT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), clientSerde));
            
    KStream<String, Foo> foos = builder.stream(FOO_TOPIC);
    
    KStream<String, Bar> bars = foos
                    .leftJoin(
                            clients,
                            (streamKey, streamValue) -> streamValue.getClientId().toString(),
                            new FooClientJoiner()
                    );
```

This basically works, but of course, the entire CLIENT_TOPIC is stored in memory(we use RocksDB to store the state, so it is on HDD), using nontrivial space - and this becomes a problem.

We do know however, that from the entire client data we use only one column - so if we had something like

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

// GlobalKTable from reduced topic
GlobalKTable<String, ReducedClient> reducedClients
    = builder.stream(CLIENT_TOPIC)
        .map((key,value) -> new KeyValue<String, String>(key, value.getTheOneColummnINeed()))
        .toGlobalKTable();
        
KStream<String, Foo> foos = builder.stream(FOO_TOPIC);

KStream<String, Bar> bars = foos
                .leftJoin(
                        reducedClients,
                        (streamKey, streamValue) -> streamValue.getClientId().toString(),
                        new FooReducedClientsJoiner()
                );
```

it would solve our problem. Creating a GlobalKTable from stream like this is not possible - but is there some equivalent for that? Or any way to reduce the space taken by the cached CLIENT_TOPIC knowing that we need just one small subset of the data?

I have also tried to manually amend the generated Client class (so that it contains only what I need), but this did not affect the resulting size of the stored GlobalKTable.

Btw, playing with the compression settings in the RocksDB did not help much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Kafka Streams to write the single column to a separate topic:

```
reducedClients
    = builder.stream(CLIENT_TOPIC)
        .map((key,value) -> new KeyValue<String, String>(key, value.getTheOneColummnINeed()))
        .to(REDUCED_TOPIC);

KStream<String, Foo> foos = builder.stream(FOO_TOPIC);

GlobalKTable<String, Client> clients
    = builder.globalTable(REDUCED_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), clientColumnSerde));

KStream<String, Bar> bars = foos
    .leftJoin(
            clients,
            (streamKey, streamValue) -> streamValue.getClientId().toString(),
            new FooReducedClientsJoiner()
    );
```

Alternatively, you should consider co-partitioning the two streams so that you can use a non-global KTable for the join.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but it requires a new topic - and that can be a non-trivial thing, depending on the company policy. So I was thinking about some local-processing based solution.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this without an intermediate topic. In general, Kafka streams generally assumes / requires that it is easy to create intermediate topics.